# ViewPager scrolling decision after button clicked in fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to control viewpager scrolling based on the condition if an imagebutton is clicked which is located in a fragment. I used a separate listener and called that listener as follows from my MainActivity:

```
mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
        public void onSwipeRight() 
{
            if (FirstFragment.btnImage.isPressed())
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "msg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();} }});
```

is my approach correct? how can I check if imagebutton touched and then unlock viewpager scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "controll" the ViewPager swipe, you have to write your
own class, extending ViewPager and overwrite the onTouchEvent methods.

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return !isEnabled() || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return !isEnabled() && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

With this way, you can simply set the viewPager.setEnable(boolean) to
en or disabled.

If you want to track click on the viewPager itself, it get's a bit more tricky.

This way, you would have to add a Gesture detector to your viewPager
implementation. Like this for example:

```
public class YourViewPager extends ViewPager {

private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;
private View.OnClickListener  listener;

public YourViewPager (Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public YourViewPager (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, new TapGestureListener()); ;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (isEnabled()) {
        gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
    return !isEnabled() || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return !isEnabled() && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
    if (isEnabled()) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll) {
    if (isEnabled()) {
        super.setCurrentItem(item, smoothScroll);
    }
}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    this.listener = l;
}

/**
 * Delegates onClick events to the listeners and invokes a smooth swipe.
 */
private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onClick(OnBoardingViewPager.this);
        }

        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }
}
```

}